# Sql query Monthly result but how?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

This query returns me first below table. forexample; 2009-06-01 00:00:00 people enter my system '41' times. i need second table

```
 declare @date1 smalldatetime, @date2 smalldatetime , @countgap int, @page nvarchar(100)   
select @date1='2009-01-01', @date2='2009-12-30 23:59:59' ,@countgap=1, @page='Tüm Sayfalar'

declare @@date1 smalldatetime,@@date2 smalldatetime , @COUNT INT          
   select @@date1=@date1, @@date2=@date2 , @COUNT=1          
   select @@date1 TARIH , @COUNT SIRA           
  INTO #TMP          
  WHILE @@date1 < @@date2           
BEGIN           
   SELECT  @@date1 = DATEadd(month,@countgap,@@date1) , @COUNT = @COUNT +1          
   INSERT INTO #TMP          
   select @@date1 TARIH , @COUNT SIRA           
END  
  select t1.TARIH, t1.SIRA, VISITINGCOUNT = isnull(t2.TARIH, 0)          
   from #TMP t1          
   left join ( 
    select count(page) as TARIH,             
      datepart(month,Date) as SIRA           
    from scr_StatisticaLog            
    where Date between @date1 and  @date2  and 
         (Page=@page or @page='Tüm Sayfalar') and 
          ProcessType='PageView'       
    GROUP BY datepart(month,Date)
             )t2 on t2.SIRA = t1.SIRA          
    order by t1.SIRA          
  return
```

```
2009-01-01 00:00:00 1   0
2009-02-01 00:00:00 2   0
2009-03-01 00:00:00 3   0
2009-04-01 00:00:00 4   1
2009-05-01 00:00:00 5   1
2009-06-01 00:00:00 6   41
2009-07-01 00:00:00 7   0
2009-08-01 00:00:00 8   0
2009-09-01 00:00:00 9   0
2009-10-01 00:00:00 10  0
2009-11-01 00:00:00 11  0
2009-12-01 00:00:00 12  1
2010-01-01 00:00:00 13  0
```

```
2009-January        12  1
```

Comment: And just what is the second table?

Comment: Are you just asking how to format dates?

Comment: yes i need '2009-January            12      1'

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DATENAME` and `DATEPART` functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188651(SQL.90).aspx) to format your date:

```
SELECT 
  DATEPART(year,DateColumn) + '-' + DATENAME(month,DateColumn) AS FormattedDate
FROM
  Table
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a [calendar table](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519) with every date in it. after that you just left join to it and get your second table.

EDIT: ahh.. new info from poster kind of invalidates this answer...

Comment: If your answer is invalidated wholly, just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Welbog's answer works.

I'd go a bit further. In MySQL land, I'd just do a left(10) on the date, and group by that. You could then do your whole query in one pass with no temp tables or loops. I think SQL server will let you substring a date, but if not you can do it by building the date as Welbog showed you.